# I have created document library template in SharePoint, How do I use another area?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, document-library, template

How I can use document library template I created into another area.

Comment: Can you please elaborate more what you trying to do..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I understand, you are trying to copy list template to another site. You have to download such list template as file from *List Template Gallery* (available from *Site Settings*) and upload it to *List Template Gallery* of target site. Then you can simply create new list based on this template (when you choose to add new app in *Site Contents*, you will be allowed to choose this template).

[More info](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Manage-list-templates-c3884ad1-bc49-44b8-b3d6-3bc6a01eb393)